# Uncheck Automatically detect proxy for Terminal Server users via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy, group-policy, internet-explorer

Good morning,

I have a registry key that changes local users Internet Explorer LAN Settings to uncheck the "Automatically detect settings" tickbox.

When I add this policy to the Terminal Servers user group it has no effect. I exported this key from my own registry after unticking the box. My computer runs Windows Vista Business Edition.

Environment: We are using Server 2008 RC2 environment - two terminal servers with a session broker.

Any idea's on how to get this working?

Comment: Can you tell us how you're adding it? Are you using GP preferences, are you using a custom template, etc?

Comment: Are you using the same version of IE on the terminal server and your browser?  Why try and find the right registry key by unchecking it on the terminal server for some user?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys.

@joeqwerty - I was importing the registry key by editing the GPO using the "New | Registry Item" wizard located at User Configuration | Preferences | Windows Settings | Registry.

@Zoredache - I was using the same version of IE on both TS environment and local desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had another GPO policy specifically for the Terminal Servers to override my GPO. I have changed this and all is working :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, sorry to not include the full solution - I didn't fully understand the settings and didn't want to give someone the incorrect information!

Anyway, the registry setting you want to change is located at:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections

Export the DefaultConnectionSettings using the "File | Export" menu option.

Open it in your favorite text editor, I use Notepad++.

The 9th hex character after the 'hex:' identifier is the one you want to change:

01 = Nothing checked.
09 = Automatically detect settings.

Try the modified key on your local machine first to make sure it works - by checking the LAN settings in IE.

If it works, then open up GP manager and edit or create what ever policy you want to apply this fix too.

Once in Edit mode, use the "New | Registry Item" wizard located at User Configuration | Preferences | Windows Settings | Registry and browse for your registry key you tested locally.

That should be it.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

IE Automatically detect settings via registry or script is simple. I have created a tool using registry key & vb-script named IE Auto Detect Settings which allows user to check & uncheck the IE “Automatically Detect Settings” option. For detail & download the tools please follow the link http://techsolutionpoint.blogspot.com/2010/12/set-ie-automatically-detect-settings.html.

Comment: It would be nice if this were a ZIP archive, as the utilities to extract RAR archives aren't bundled with Windows. (And the benefits of RAR compression aren't needed for such a small archive…)